# Clarifying local magnetic moment axes in VASP: cartesian vs crystal (for MAGMOM/M_CONSTR)

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-mechanics, magnetism, vesta

In VASP, one can set the local magnetic moments of each ion in a non-collinear SOC calculation along a certain direction using the [MAGMOM](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/MAGMOM)/[M_CONSTR](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/M_CONSTR) tags. The manual linked to states that these local magnetic moments should be given in Cartesian coordinates for each ion (e.g., $M_{1x}, M_{1y}, M_{1z}$).

Let's say I have a triangular lattice as visualized in VESTA below:
[image]

When I calculate exchange J anisotropic couplings using [the 4-state method](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/dt/c2dt31662e/), I have to set the magnetism along different directions. My question is: I want to calculate the exchange couplings for the pair of sites highlighted in blue. For this, how do I define MAGMOM/M_CONSTR? This bond is in the $b$ direction (red arrow). How do I define MAGMOM/M_CONSTR to have the code set the magnetic moment along this red arrow direction? Naively, I would have done MAGMOM = 0 1 0, but if MAGMOM/M_CONSTR uses Cartesian coordinates, wouldn't this set the direction along the vertical/orange arrow? Or is this not the case? I could not find any clarifying information in the VASP documentation (unless I missed something).
I think it would make most sense if I set MAGMOM = 0 1 0 for this, but I am not sure whether there are any subtleties here, and whether I should have instead used MAGMOM = $-0.5$ $(\sqrt{3}/2)$ $0$ (i.e. the unit (1 0 0) vector rotated 120 degrees counterclockwise).

Is there anything I can do to check which direction exactly the VASP code chooses? The OUTCAR file can give "magnetixation (x)" etc, but I still don't know what axis frame it uses.

I would appreciate any clarification.